# Auth_token error at Facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook

i have been on this for the last 2 days with no result.
i am running my facebook app on my localhost with port-forwarding method.
i know my server setup is working fine as i can see the logs on the django runserver and dyndns log as well.

django is properly responding to calls as well.

the problem is as soon as the app authorizes with my user account, it straight follows to the page that says this:

```
Errors while loading page from application

The URL http://amitverma.dyndns.org/facebook_sample/?auth_token=817f8fbe99eff10582b634589de17b84 is not valid.

Please try again later. We appreciate your patience as the developers of app_test and Facebook resolve this issue. Thanks!
```

I am making a test app learning from facebook + django tutorial from [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:PyFacebook_Tutorial) and [here](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/02/how-to-build-a-facebook-app-in-django/).
I am still getting this error and I have no idea what i am doing wrong...
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This often happens with a failed authentication.  I'm not sure what the Python client libraries might look like, but with the PHP ones you generally make an authorization call against the library, something like `$facebook->require_login()`.

With the PHP library, if this call fails to verify the user's Facebook session, then it automatically outputs HTML that will redirect the browser and try to re-establish the session, hence the `auth_token` parameter.

I suspect you're running into something similar.  Try to isolate any authentication calls you're making, and use a Firefox extension like [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) to see if you are undergoing any redirects during the requests.

Answer (score 0):

When you get that error, presuming you have `debug=True` in the Django settings and that your application is in development mode in Facebook, you can do View Source and see the entire Django error page that would normally display, including traceback. Facebook comment it out in the HTML so it doesn't show on the front end, but you can copy and paste it into a separate HTML file and view that in your browser to see the nice friendly Django error page which will definitely give you a clue as to what's going wrong.